# Which are the most useful resources to learn to draw the UML class diagram in Visio?

Tags: visio

I am stuck at properly aligning the generalization arrow between the classes. I could not make them appear as in the UML books.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visio UML stencils are not very good and is very frustrating to work with them. Have a look at http://softwarestencils.com/uml/index.html, there are some very nice, free stencil updates for Visio UML 2.0. It takes very little time to get used to them. After I used them I never looked back.

Answer (score 1):

[UML Model Diagrams - Visio - Microsoft Office Online](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio/CH010266691033.aspx)

One note. If you want UML diagramm looks like classic book examples you should use Rational Rose instead of Visio.